# Node.js : How to check if mongojs connected successfully?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, connection, mongojs

Im making a server and need some way to be identified if mongojs connected successfully to the mongodb database when i call the function :

```
    mongojs.connect(connectionString, collections);
```

Is there a callback or an event listener i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in MongoJS docs (https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#events), there is one event which you can listen to know when the db is ready:

```
db.on('ready',function() {
    console.log('database connected');
});
```

You need to make a variable assignment of the sentence you posted, as I show you below:

```
var db = mongojs.connect(connectionString, collections);
```

and then use the ready event to listen the db connection

Comment: I see :) thank you. But is there an event to tell me it failed?

Comment: I see there is an "error" event but as I've tried, it doesn't get called if a connection to the database failed

Comment: I didn't tried it, but I suggest you to use the official [MongoDB Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) or [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) instead MongoJS. Those frameworks give you a lot of more options than MongoJS.

Comment: Right i will definitely give those a look :) thanks for your help!

Comment: mongojs does not open a connection until the first request is made.  You need to use db.open() to force it to connect before any requests.